# setEnableVolumeLogger not found

Tags: android, react-native, webrtc, react-native-webrtc

I am using the latest version of react-native-webrtc (106.0.7). When I try to build the android project, I’m getting these errors:

```
> /react-native-webrtc/android/src/main/java/com/oney/WebRTCModule/WebRTCModule.java:129:
> error: cannot find symbol adm =
> JavaAudioDeviceModule.builder(reactContext).setEnableVolumeLogger(false).createAudioDeviceModule();
> 

> /react-native-webrtc/android/src/main/java/com/oney/WebRTCModule/SerializeUtils.java:59:
> error: an enum switch case label must be the unqualified name of an
> enumeration constant case STOPPED:
```

The required method `setEnableVolumeLogger` and the enumeration `STOPPED` are not available in the `JavaAudioDeviceModule`.

How can I fix this issue?

Comment: Try to update your WebRTC library

Comment: @BernardoAlmeida I'm already using the latest version